# Does Topaz have any usage?

Tags: mine-blocks

So I play Mine Blocks yesterday and I was mining when I found this blue ore. I mined it and it said **topaz**. I tried doing the following:

1. Using it in a crafting table. Trying to turn it into a blocks by putting it in all slots. Also trying to make tools.
2. Smelting it.

Nothing happened. I wonder what usage topaz has. Does topaz have any usage?